# Karma-Mocha - How to test method that listens to DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am writing tests for an internal framework that my company maintains. In it there is a method that is equivalent to jQuery's `$(document).ready(handler)` method. The method looks like this:

```
export function $ready(fn) {
    document.readyState === 'complete' ?
        $exec(fn) :
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            $exec(fn);
        });
}
```

I would like to be able to write a test that will execute the event listener callback rather than immediately executing `fn`, however I do not know of a way to get my test to execute before `readyState` is set to `complete`, nor do I know of a way to re-trigger the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

re-trigger `DOMContentLoaded`

```
// Create the event.
var event = document.createEvent('Event');

// Define that the event name is 'DOMContentLoaded'.
event.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', true, true);

window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then you can test it

```
describe('Some feature', function() {
  it('should increase the number of div', function(){
    expect(document.querySelector('div')).to.equal(10);
    // retrigger DOMContentLoaded event here
    expect(document.querySelector('div')).to.equal(15);
  });
});
```

[createEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)